# Tokusatsu hero throws monster into the air, exclaims "Prepare for ultrablast!"

Tags: story-identification, tokusatsu

As a kid in the late 70's and early 80's, I eagerly watched a number of [Tokusatsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokusatsu) shows from Japan. There's a scene from one of them that's stuck with me for all these years, but I've been unable to identify what show it's from.

What I recall is pretty brief: at the climax of a battle with a monster, the show's hero hurls the monster into the air and says "Prepare for ultrablast!"  Then he waves his arms around for a few moments before aiming a tremendous blast of energy directly upwards, which strikes the monster and blows it to smithereens.

Based on the name of the finishing move I long assumed this must have been from the show *Ultraman*, but when I watched the first season a while back I didn't see the scene.  Also, Ultraman (famously, as I later learned) only ever utters the word *SHUWATCH!!!*, so it doesn't seem possible he could be the hero I remember, unless there was some overzealous English translation going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if you are thinking of [*Spectreman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectreman)?

[image: Spectreman]

- Tokusatsu? CHECK!
- [Crazy arm waving?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNdsXuagMFY#t=19m34s) CHECK!
- Monster fighting and throwing? CHECK!
- Spectre-Flash (super powered ray)? CHECK!
- Speaks more than one word? CHECK!

Comment: *"Prepare for ultrablast!”?*

Comment: @Valorum I presume that was misremembered. :) I didn't have the stomach to sit through all 67 episodes of Spectreman to find a use of the flash power (nor the separate ray power), to find a similar declaration.

Comment: "*I didn't have the stomach to sit through all 67 episodes*" -> I'm so tempted to call you a 'casual' right now.

Comment: @Valorum Adoro, but given the amount of other geek reread/rewatch/relisten I am doing this month, I am gonna cling tightly to my geek pride. ;D

Comment: If you're not sacrificing sleep in return for imaginary internet points, you need to re-evaluate your priorities.

Comment: @Valorum Who sez I am not sacrificing my sleep?!?

Comment: I expect a proper answer to this by Sunday night. That's ample time to watch every episode.